# The presence of $\zeta^{\mu}(k)$ in the Ward-Takahashi identities in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, polarization, ward-identity

On page 132 of [Timo Weigand's QFT notes](https://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/624b/WeigandQFT.pdf) we introduce the Ward-Takahashi identity for QED, this is the statement that:

$$k^{\mu}\mathcal M_{\mu}(k)=0 \tag{5.35},$$

with

$$\mathcal M(k)=\zeta^{\mu}(k)\mathcal M_{\mu}(k) \tag{5.34}$$

My problem is that in all calculations of $\mathcal M$ that I have seen before with an external photon - for example on page 120 we find:

$$i\mathcal M_{fi}=(ie)^2\left[ \bar v_{-r}(q)\gamma^\nu\frac{i(\gamma t-m_0)}{t^2-m_0^2+i\epsilon}\gamma^\mu u_s(p)\epsilon_\nu^*(q',\lambda')\epsilon_\mu^*(p',\lambda)+\bar v_{-r}(q)\gamma^\nu \frac{i(\gamma t'+m_0)}{t'^2-m_0^2+i\epsilon}\gamma^\mu u_s(p)\epsilon_\nu^*(p',\lambda)\epsilon_\mu^*(q',\lambda') \right]\tag{4.109},$$

at tree level - I don't see the polarization vector $\zeta^{\mu}(k)$ appearing *anywhere* here, so how can we possibly factor it out of $\mathcal M$ as we seem to be doing in $5.34$?

I can only think of one possible resolution to this, that this appears at higher order in the QED Feynman diagrams. If this isn't the case, I do not see where it comes from.

Comment: $\epsilon_\mu$ is the polarization tensor.

Comment: @Prahar I thought about this too, but $\epsilon^{\mu}$ are the basis vectors that produce $\zeta^{\mu}$, they're not the same thing, right?

Comment: They are not, but in the W-T identity is derived by replacing the polarization tensor (_any_ polarization tensor) by $k^\mu$.

Comment: @Prahar Ok thank you for your comments, I've had a think about it and would I be right to say that the point here is that for our general external photon state which we can write $|\vec k,\vec \zeta\rangle=|\vec k,\vec \zeta_T\rangle+|\vec k,\vec \zeta_S\rangle$ where $\vec \zeta_T$ and $\vec \zeta_S$ represent the transverse and "spurious state" polarizations respectively, because $\vec \zeta_S\propto \vec k$ then the statement that $\zeta^{\mu}\mathcal M_{\mu}\propto k^{\mu}\mathcal M_{\mu}=0$ for the spurious states, implies that their contribution to the correlation functions is zero?